# Cogrouping Datasets in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I am trying to cogroup two datasets in pyspark, but I keep receiving an 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable error. Do I need to parallelize the data before I cogroup?

```
PlayerRDD = dfPlayer.rdd.map(lambda x: [x["age"],(x[col1], x[col2], x[col3], x[col4], x[col5])])
CoachRDD = dfCoach.rdd.map(lambda x: [x["age"],(x[col1], x[col2], x[col3], x[col4])])
cogroupResults = PlayerRDD.cogroup(CoachRDD)
[(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(cogroupResults)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this.

```
cogroupResults = PlayerRDD.cogroup(CoachRDD)*.collect()*
```